# linux + convert file format columns to one column

Tags: text-processing, awk, perl

I have the following file (Linux.txt)

```
linux-test01 linuxER
LinuxCV      LinuxWE LinuxPL
LinuxDF      LinuxXC LinuxSD     LinuxAQ
```

how to print using awk or perl one-liner to produce the following output ( output will be in new file - LinuxNewOrder.txt )

```
linux-test01
LinuxCV 
LinuxDF
linuxER
LinuxWE
LinuxXC
LinuxPL
LinuxSD
LinuxAQ
```

so second column will be after the first and third column will be after the second, and so on.

Comment: Is the `more Linux.txt` part of the file content and needs to disappear? If not edit your post so that it is clear that is the command to show the file.

Comment: no the file Linux.txt should be stay as is the new output should be on diff new file

Comment: If the line `more Linux.txt` should stay, you should put that in your expected output.

Comment: Linux.txt is only the original file , what I mean is awk will read the file Linux.txt and create a new file - LinuxNewOrder.txt with the new order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using combination of `awk` and `grep` :

```
awk -v RS=" " '{print}' Linux.txt | grep . > LinuxNewOrder.txt
```

more simpler one, using `xargs` :

```
xargs -n 1 < Linux.txt > LinuxNewOrder.txt
```

Comment: If I am understanding correctly, the question is about a top-down sort column by column, your answer is about a left-right sort row by row.

Comment: @lgaggini that's right. Thanks for spotting out. I will correct it.

Answer (score 1):

Just using awk, printing the 1st column of the input, then the 2nd, ...

```
awk '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) a[i] = a[i] "\n" $i }
  END  { for (i in a) print substr(a[i], 2) }' Linux.txt
```

Using array `a`, for each column `i` the fields `$i` are concatenated, separated by newline, into `a[i]`. At the end of the input, `a[i]` contains the complete column i. Finally the columns are printed in order, omitting the `"\n" which was stuffed in before`$1`.

Comment: @phk Thanks, I wondered why it did not look like my draft, forgot about monospaced fonts. It is my first post here, so I'm still learning the ropes... :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate column by column working on awk index print field:

```
for i in $(seq $(awk '{print NF}' linux.txt | sort -nu | tail -n 1)); do awk -v field=$i '{print $field}' linux.txt | grep -v "^$"; done > LinuxNewOrder.txt

$ cat LinuxNeworder.txt
linux-test01
LinuxCV
LinuxDF
linuxER
LinuxWE
LinuxXC
LinuxPL
LinuxSD
LinuxAQ
```

Some more explanation:

- `awk '{print NF}' linux.txt | sort -nu | tail -n 1`: [get max number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5761234/1667104)
- `awk -v field=$i '{print $field}' linux.txt`: print column by column using the `i` bash variable as column index
- `grep -v "^$"`: remove empty field